# MySQL statement: spliting rows values into new columns

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL I need to return new first/last name columns for each user in table1.

```
**Table1**  
uid  
1  
2  

**Table2**  
id   fid   uid   field_value  
1    1     1     Joe  
2    2     1     Blow  
3    1     2     Joe  
4    2     2     Blogs

**Result**
uid   first_name   last_name
1     Joe          Blow
2     Joe          Blogs
```

Comment: Be careful using this approach. The more fields you want to extract, the more joins you need. Big joins are costy in MySQL. Joining just 3 tables with 30K rows in each, can take up to 1-5 minutes, despite having all the indices and being cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple,

```
select t1.uid, t21.field_value first_name, t22.field_value last_name
from table1 t1, table2 t21, table2 t22
where t1.uid=t21.uid and t1.uid=t22.uid and t21.fid=1 and t22.fid=2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (not tested):

```
select a.uid, a.field_value first_name, b.field_value last_name
from table2 a inner join table2 b on a.uid = b.uid 
where a.fid = 1 and b.fid = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming you have columns first_name, and last_name in table2:

```
select uid, first_name, last_name from table1 left join table2 on table1.uid=table2.uid
```